# Let $X$ have the exponential distribution with $\lambda=2$ Find the density function of the random variable $Y=\ln(X)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have an answer but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right:
$f(x)$ is the pdf $f(x)=2e^{-2x}$, then, if the random variable $Y=\ln(X)$, then we simply substitute:

$P(Y \leq y)$=

$P(2e^{-2X} \leq y)$

$P(-4X \leq y)$ *since $y=ln(x)$*

$P(X \leq - \dfrac {1} {4} y)$

This is the distribution function, right?

Thanks!

Comment: Wait, how did $Y$ turn into $2e^{-2X}$? I thought that $Y=\ln X$.

Comment: See, that's what I'm not sure about, which order to do the substitutions in!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also attempt a change of variable. Since $Y = \log X$ is one-to-one over $(0,\infty)$, then $X = \exp\{Y\}$, and the density of $Y$ is
$$f_Y(y) = \frac{f_X(e^y)}{\left|\frac{dy}{dx}\right|_{e^y}} = f_X(e^y)\left|\frac{dx}{dy}\right|_{e^y} = 2 e^{-2e^y}\cdot e^y = 2e^{-2e^y+y}.$$

---

Recall that $F_X(x) = 1-e^{-\lambda x}$. Then
\begin{align*}
P(Y<y) &= P(\log X <y)\\
&=P(X< e^y)\\
&=F_X(e^y)\\
&=1-e^{-2e^y}.
\end{align*}
Taking the derivative gives the density,
$$f_Y(y) = -e^{-2e^y}\cdot (-2e^y) = 2e^{-2e^y+y}.$$

Answer (score 1):

When $Y=\ln X$, then you get the distribution function of $Y$ as follows:
$$P(Y\leq y) = P(\ln X\leq y) = P(X\leq e^y)$$
Notice there is nothing weird going on. Instead of $Y$, I simply substitute $\ln X$, because they are equal. And in the last equality, I take the exponential on both sides of the inequality inside the probability.

But in the title, it seems like you are looking for the density, and not the distribution function, but I assumed you wanted to find the distribution function first.

Comment: If I want the pdf, I know it's the derivative of the cumulative df. It's hard for me to tell exactly what I have to do since the only examples in the book are using $X$ ~ $U(0,1)$ And what happened to the exponential distribution of X?

Comment: @Jabernet you know that $P(X\leq e^y) = \int_0^ {e^{y}} 2e^{-2x}\ dx$, since $X$ has an exponential distribution. So you need to find the derivative of this expression with respect to $y$. The result will be the density of $Y$.