# Random variable X has exponential density $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$. Then comment on $Var(logX)$

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value

Let $\lambda>0$, Random variable X has exponential density $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ on $[0,\infty)$. Then $Var(logX)$:

1. is strictly increasing in $\lambda$
2. is strictly decreasing in $\lambda$
3. does not depend on $\lambda$
4. first increases and then decreases in $\lambda$

My attempt:

If $X \sim \exp (\lambda)$, then what does $\log(X)$ follow, or what is its moment generating function? If I can find that, then I can find the expression for $Var(X)$, hence find $\frac{dVar(X)}{d\lambda}$ and the second derivative and decide if it is increasing or depressing.

I am using the solution given in [Let $X$ have the exponential distribution with $\lambda=2$ Find the density function of the random variable $Y=\ln(X)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1579261/let-x-have-the-exponential-distribution-with-lambda-2-find-the-density-func)

Then $Y=log(X)$ has the pdf $f(y)=\lambda e^{-\lambda e^y+y}$

Now, $Var(Y)=E(Y^2)-[E(Y)]^2$

$E(Y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y \lambda e^{-\lambda e^y+y} dy$ and $E(Y^2)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y^2 \lambda e^{-\lambda e^y+y} dy$.

I am having trouble integrating these. 
Is there any other approach?

Comment: Whats $V$? Variance?

Comment: @Tom yes V is variance

Comment: Not sure that $\log(X)$ is integrable...

Comment: I think it is integrable indeed.

Comment: @Diya Maybe you can use the [Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule), since you have to calculate the derivative of $E(Y)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach.

---

Observe that  $U:=\lambda X$ has exponential distribution with parameter $1$.

Based on that we find: $$\mathsf{Var}(\ln X)=\mathsf{Var}\left(\ln\left(\frac1{\lambda}U\right)\right)=\mathsf{Var}(\ln U-\ln\lambda)=\mathsf{Var}(\ln U)\tag1$$and we are released from the annoying parameter now.

It is enough now to solve the following integrals:$$\mathbb E[\ln U]=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-u}\ln u\;du$$and:$$\mathbb E[\ln U]^2=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-u}(\ln u)^2\;du$$

I hope that they are easier to find.

Comment: If we are free from the parameter here, they can't we conclude from there itself that #3 is the correct answer? Is integrating necessary anymore?

Comment: Oh, yes of course! Actually I did not even see the points 1,2,3,4 (sorry) and only focused on finding the variance. On its own (1) in my answer is a full answer already (glad that I did not dive into solving the integrals ;-))